Unable to extend fedora Server VirtualBox Volume (lvm2)
I Im trying to resize my root volume. I already resized the virtual volume inside virtualbox and also reallocated the space with gparted:

But undortunately after using lvextend and resize2fs there is an error stating: couldn't find valid filesystem superblock


that means your file system isn't understood by resize2fs, so it's probably not ext2/ext3/ext4. Check the file system type with df -T.

Ok thanks to Marcus I checked the filesystem and it was xfs so instead of using resize2fs I had to use xfs_growfs instead.
sudo xfs_growfs -d /dev/fedora/root
